# Payment methode with stripe in flutterflow

Tags: stripe-payments, flutterflow

i'm try to build mobile app with stripe payment method in flutterflow so went i press button for payment i received some message **unknown error occurred**
then i checked the console and i saw this message. help me please
[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4h8P.png)

i though the problem was stripe integration but it was correct deployed in flutterflow. i try to redeploy it and add static value to the button payment and i get the same problem